# Lightest possible orbital rocket - being launched from high altitude

Tags: rockets, rocket-equation, high-altitude-launch

Iv'e been looking into micro-satellites launches on small rockets - from what I could find the lightest rocket to deploy a satellite into LEO is the SS-520-4 which had a weight of 2600kg.

If hypothetically, you could set up the launchpad at a height of 30,000m - how much lighter would you be able to create the whole thing? (considering all you want is to put the same 3kg satellite into orbit).

I understand it **could** be lighter, due to gaining some free altitude + clearing the portion with the highest air resistence off of the route. but I wonder by what factor.

Couldn't really think of any trivial way to calculate it, any pointing at the right direction for an answer would be apricciated.

Comment: There will be some logistical problems in building a launch site with a 30km start altitude; Everest is only 8.8km high.

Comment: Thats exactly why I opened with "If hypothetically you could"...

Comment: How about orbital launch from a balloon? https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35158/what-is-happening-with-zero2infinity-and-the-bloostar

Comment: For those interested, the SS-520-4 launch is discussed in http://spaceflight101.com/ss-520-4-rocket-launches-on-experimental-mission/